# Getting half size of UIImage from URL by Afnetworking 2.0

Tags: objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2

I am doing like following to determine the size of the downloaded image during the block and then i will set the size of the uiimageview accordingly.
How can get the actual size of UIImage by Afnetworking, Please help me.

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: str1]];

```
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.imageView;

[cell.imageView  setImageWithURLRequest:request
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plceholder-50X60.png"]
                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
 {
     NSLog(@"image = %f, imageheight = %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);

     UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; //make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
     if (!strongImageView) return;

 }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

What the size of the image depends on the name of the image file on disk.

If the file's name is `Plceholder-50X60.png`, its actual size is `image.size` with `image.scale`  1.0, but if its name is `Plceholder-50X60@2x.png`, its actual size would be `CGSizeMake(image.size.width*image.scale, image.size.height*image.scale)` with `image.scale` 2.0.

The trick is in the `imageNamed:` method, see the reference of `imageNamed:`:

> On a device running iOS 4 or later, the behavior is identical if the
>   device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If the screen has a scale of 2.0,
>   this method first searches for an image file with the same filename
>   with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is
>   button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads
>   that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object
>   to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale
>   property to 1.0.

Conclusion: You can get the actual size of the image using `CGSizeMake(image.size.width*image.scale, image.size.height*image.scale)` no matter what the name of image file is.